# MySQL query and PHP: how to know how many results per each "WHERE" condition

Tags: php, mysql

im using php and I have this mysql query :

```
SELECT * FROM numbers
        WHERE 
        ( XXX LIKE '999' AND YYY RLIKE '[0-9]88[0-9]') 
        OR 
        ( XXX LIKE '111' AND YYY RLIKE '[0-9]23[0-9]')
```

My Question: 
how can I know how many results I get from ( XXX LIKE '999' AND YYY RLIKE '[0-9]88[0-9]')  and how many results i get from ( XXX LIKE '111' AND YYY RLIKE '[0-9]23[0-9]') and so on.
I dont want to split them into two queries because i have many of these conditions in my query. plus i still want to get the result that satisfies the conditions. please help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT *,
       SUM(CASE WHEN XXX LIKE '999' AND YYY RLIKE '[0-9]88[0-9]' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Count999,
       SUM(CASE WHEN XXX LIKE '111' AND YYY RLIKE '[0-9]23[0-9]' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Count111
    FROM numbers
    WHERE 
    ( XXX LIKE '999' AND YYY RLIKE '[0-9]88[0-9]') 
    OR 
    ( XXX LIKE '111' AND YYY RLIKE '[0-9]23[0-9]')
```

Comment: can u tell me please how to get count999 and count111 in php variables. thank u so much for ur help.

Answer (score 0):

I think it'd be something like:

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM numbers WHERE XXX LIKE '999' AND YYY RLIKE '[0-9]88[0-9]') AS 'CountA',
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM numbers WHERE XXX LIKE '111' AND YYY RLIKE '[0-9]23[0-9]') AS 'CountB'
```

Answer (score -1):

use the function [mysql_num_rows](https://www.php.net/mysql_num_rows).

Comment: mysql_num_rows will show how many results returned this query not how many results have each of them.